When can a Banach space be a dual space and the extreme points of $l_{\infty}$
It is known that if the set of extreme points of the unit ball of an infinite dimensional Banach space say $X,$ is finite, then X cannot be a dual space. However, it seems that the extreme points of $B_{l_{\infty}}$ is just the constant $1$ and constant $-1$ sequence (I'm considering the field to be $\mathbb{R}$) and $l_{\infty} \cong l_1^*$. Where have I gone wrong?

extreme points are all sequences with elements of absolute value 1.

thanks. Should I delete the question?
